# how to convert a database backup to csv or xls file

Tags: excel, sed, converters, csv

I have a database backup file with data is a long line separated by below delimiters

field delimiter is `~^`

row delimiter is `^~`

how do I convert it into rows and put them in columns.

I just want to be able to convert it into comma separated values so that i could use excel to work with the data. I know SED tool could help accomplish but are there any other alternatives where i could achieve that.

i have tried `notepad++` but unable to figure it out either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using GNU awk for multi-char RS:

```
awk -v RS='\^~' -F'~\^' -v OFS=, '{$1=$1}1' file
```

If you don't have GNU awk then get it but if you can't then simplest is probably:

```
awk -F'~\^' -v OFS=, '{gsub(/\^~/,ORS); $1=$1}1' file
```

The above is untested since no sample input and expected output was provided.